# set new element class property value

Tags: javascript, dom

How to add 10px to an css class property with javascript?

for example:

```
var bigger = document.getElementsByClassName("size200").style.width;
bigger + 10;
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.size200').width($('.size200').width() + 10);
});` maybe with jQuery?

Comment: I want to know how to do it with plain javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result ,use below option

```
let width = document.getElementsByClassName("size200")[0].clientWidth + 10;
document.getElementsByClassName("size200")[0].style.width = width + 'px'
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/roazyL

```js
let width = document.getElementsByClassName("size200")[0].clientWidth + 10;
document.getElementsByClassName("size200")[0].style.width = width + 'px'
```

```css
.size200{
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px
}

.size100{
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="size200">
  
</div>

<div class="size200">
  
</div>

<div class="size100">
  
</div>
```

Above solution will change only first class , to apply for every element with same class

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("size200").length; i++){
    let width = document.getElementsByClassName("size200")[i].clientWidth + 10;
    document.getElementsByClassName("size200")[i].style.width = width + 'px'
}
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vvEJRz

Answer (score 1):

```js
setTimeout(() => {

  // get width
  let width = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.some-class')).width;
  width = +width.substr(0,width.length-2);
  let newWidth = `${width+100}px`;
  
  // set style
  Array(document.getElementsByClassName('some-class').length)
    .fill()
    .map((_, index) => {
      document.getElementsByClassName('some-class')[index].style.width = newWidth;
    });
    
}, 1000)
```

```css
.some-class {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-class"></div>
<p>
wait 1s
</p>
<div class="some-class"></div>
```

Comment: Not working. I'm trying to do this: document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 87) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("size200").style.width +=10
    }
};

Comment: @MATKALI indeed it didn't worked. I updated a snippet solution that works.